# Error in instantiating bean in Spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractBusinessModule {

}

public class MS3BusinessModule extends AbstractBusinessModule 
{
    public MS3BusinessModule(SomeOtherClass value)
    {

    }
}
```

And the following bean declarations:

```
<bean id="ms3BusinessModule" class="com.hba.MS3BusinessModule" >
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <ref bean="someOtherBeanID"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>
```

Upon startup of my application I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ms3BusinessModule' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.hba.MS3BusinessModule]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.hba.EhCacheTest.main(EhCacheTest.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.hba.MS3BusinessModule]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:212)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112)
    at org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean.setBeanFactory(ScopedProxyFactoryBean.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitConstructors(Enhancer.java:721)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:499)
    at net.sf.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:200)
    ... 16 more
```

What could be going wrong?

If I remove the `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` from the bean declaration it works.

Update: If I put a default constructor in `MS3BusinessModule`, it works. I do not understand the reason why a default constructor is required. can somebody explain please.

Comment: What does `AbstractBusinessModule` look like?

Comment: Isn't that a thing in java when you have a parametrised  constructor you must define a default constructor?

Comment: @SrinivasR no, _if_ you want a no-arg constructor _and_ you also have ones that take arguments _then_ you need to make the no-arg one explicit, but it's fine for a class to have no default constructor at all.

Comment: @IanRoberts.... So don't I need to define a default or no args constructor even class contains a constructor with arguments?

Comment: @SrinivasR every class must have cat least one constructor. If you don't define _any_ constructors at all then the compiler will add a no-arg one for you which just calls `super()` but if you provide any explicit constructors of your own then the compiler assumes you know what you mean and doesn't add an extra one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I put a default constructor in MS3BusinessModule, it works. I do not understand the reason why a default constructor is required. can somebody explain please.

The way `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` works is to hide away the "real" bean under a different name and create a CGLIB proxy class which is a subclass of the real bean's class, and which delegates all method calls to the correct instance of the target bean.  So you have two different kinds of object here:

- *n* instances of `com.hba.MS3BusinessModule` for each session/request/whatever the scope is, and
- one singleton instance of the dynamically generated proxy class.

The *n* target beans are constructed using the constructor that takes arguments, with your `<constructor-arg>` values passed to it, but the proxy class needs a no-arg superclass constructor to call (which could of course be declared `protected` rather than `public`).  The proxy mechanism will never actually call any of the superclass methods on the proxy instance as all calls go to the target instance(s) instead, but the proxy class needs to extend the target bean class in order for the proxy to be an `instanceof` the right type.

An alternative fix is to provide an *interface* that `M3BusinessModule` implements, and make all references by other beans to this one use the interface type rather than the concrete class type.  This will allow Spring to use a `java.lang.reflect` proxy instead of a CGLIB one, implementing the interface without needing to extend the concrete class.