# Use Spring AOP on class with final members and no default constructor

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, cglib

I am trying to use spring aop.
I have configured the following Aspect:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class BenchmarkAspect {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BenchmarkAspect.class);

    @Around(value = "@annotation(benchmark)")
    public void do(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final Benchmark benchmark)            throws Throwable {

    logger.error("Before");
    joinPoint.proceed();
    logger.error("After");
}
```

And this is an example for a class using my costume annotation

```
@Component
public class AttributeContainer {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AttributeContainer.class);
    private final int y;

    public AttributeContainer(int y){
          this.y = y;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void getAttribute() {
         logger.error("Inside Attribute call...");
    }
}
```

When I load my application I get the following exception:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not  generate CGLIB subclass of class [class   com.test.AttributeContainer]: Common causes of this problem   include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments   were given:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitConstructors(Enhancer.java:721)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:499)
at net.sf.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:201)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:476)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
```

**Update**
Adding my spring config xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.*" />

  <bean id="test" class="com.test.AttributeContainer">
    <constructor-arg value="34"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Why the CGlib is failing to create a sub class??
Thanks!

Comment: I am familiar with AspectJ, but not with Spring AOP. Anyway, maybe I can see or suggest something if you provide a complete, compileable, minimal code sample reproducing your problem. Your question is a bit too unspecific.

Comment: Thanks! I have added more details to my question. @kriegaex

Comment: Does it work if you provide a no-arg ctor?

Comment: I can't.. because y is final. @Dave Newton

Comment: Check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664996/error-in-instantiating-bean-in-spring-3-1

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Comment: `@Component` is "java config" xml config is .... (basically same) but xml! (they can conflict/cooperate)  ...xml looks ok, to make it work with java config: You can use `@Value`/`@Qualifier` annotation...or (removing `@Component`) initialize it (manually) as a `@Bean` inside a `@Configuration`( like).

Comment: so (with the few given) i am quite confident that, removing `@Component` from `AttributeContainer` will work/produce "next" error... (since xml does exactly this: init manually, as "bean", inside "config like")

Answer (score 0):

please define a no args public or default type constructor inside the class of targeted method for adviceMethod.Hope, it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

> `Could not instantiate bean class [...]: No default constructor found`

This looks more like a Spring bean configuration/instantiation problem than anything connected with Spring AOP or AspectJ.

After you will have fixed this, you will probably run into other problems:

- In your advice `@Around(value = "@annotation(benchmark)")` you should take care of spelling. I guess you want your annotation `Benchmark` to begin with a capital "B", not a lower-case one.
- Where does your second advice parameter `final Benchmark benchmark` come from? It is not bound via `args`, `this` or `target`. You do not use it in your advice anyway, so you can just remove it.

---

**Update** to answer your additional question:

```
AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class
[class com.test.AttributeContainer]: Common causes of this problem
include using a final class or a non-visible class;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
```

This exception message seems pretty self-explanatory. Have you read it? You instantiate your component without parameters, but only provide a constructor which absolutely needs a parameter. This is why Spring complains. Maybe you want to read a Spring tutorial?

Comment: You are correct about the init problem. I fix the problem and got the above exception ( I updated the main question ). BTW, the @annotation(benchmark) works, but I will change it anyway..!Thanks! @kriegaex , any idea about the updated exception?

Comment: Then how can you explain the fact that when I remove the annotation from AttributeContainer I get no exception, so Spring wise I am good. My problem is that from some reason the CGLIB cannot subclass AttributeContainer. I have added my spring config xml to show you that the AttributeContainer is properly  initialized. @kriegaex

Comment: CGLIB creates a dynamic proxy. This is how Spring implements AOP. CGLIB requires the class to be proxied to provide a default constructor. So please provide one. Or switch to full-blown AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. It also works inside Spring.

Comment: I can't provide a default constructor, because of my final member. But  I can try using AspectJ, I read about it, can you give me a direction?  What would you do different? @kriegaex And thank you for you comments!

Comment: AspectJ syntax is a superset of Spring AOP syntax. You can do the same things as with Spring AOP plus many more, and you do not need any Java or CGLIB dynamic proxies. At http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/ you find the tool as well as documentation.